# Get amended list from list.remove() in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was surprised to see the following behavior in python:

```
>>> x = ['A','F']
>>> print x
['A', 'F']
>>> x.remove('A')
>>> print x
['F']
>>> ['A','F'].remove('A')
>>> print ['A','F'].remove('A')
None
```

The first four commands show the intended operation of `.remove()`. In the last two commands, though, it appears that the return value for the remove function is `None` instead of the amended list, which seems strange to me.

I want to do something like:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = []
list2.append(list1.remove('a'))
print list2   # returns [None] instead of [['a','b']]
```

I could do:

```
list2.append([x for x in list1 if x != 'a'])
```

but this is much harder to read/understand in my opinion. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your two solutions are not equivalent -- only the first one mutates `list1`. If you want that to occur, why not perform the operation in two steps?

Comment: Why not `list1[1:]`?

Comment: As @FrédéricHamidi said, it should be `list2.extend([x for x in list1 if x != 'a'])` to be get the same result.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I guess I was thinking that if I did it in another operation it wouldn't change the original list. I don't want to original list changed, so it looks like I need to do the second version.

Comment: @WoLy `list[1:]` doesn't work because I need to remove by value, not by location. Sometimes I'll be removing 'b' or 'c' instead.

Comment: `remove` method removes the first item, use slice with index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remove operation is *in place* - it modifies the list the operation is performed on instead of returning a new list. There isn't a real need to return the "modified" list, because the list remove was called on is still available.

So `print list.remove(x)` printing `None` is expected.

What's wrong with:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = []
list1.remove('a')
list2.append(list1)
print list2
```

Are you just trying to reduce the lines of code?

Comment: I need list1 in its original form after appending part of it to list2. But I guess this suggests that using `remove()` causes it to change anyway so this isn't a good solution to my problem.

Comment: In that case then append list1 to list2 and then peform the remove operation on list2 after.

Comment: If you simply append `list1` then remove the element from `list2[0]`, that will change `list1`, because they are the same object. If you don't want `list1` to be changed, then you should copy the contents e.g. `list2.append(list(list1))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using append with a list comprehension,

```
list2.append([x for x in list1 if x != 'a'])
```

then I would suggest splitting it into a couple of lines to make it easier to read.

```
new_list = [x for x in list1 if x != 'a']
list2.append(new_list)
```

Alternatively, if you find the list comprehension hard to understand, you could simply copy the list then remove the element that you don't want.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new_list = list(list1) # copy the entire list
new_list.remove('a')
list2.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`index(item)` returns the lowest index in list that item appears.
`remove` removes the first item found, so we can use `slice with index` to get same result in one line without changing `list1`:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = []

index = list1.index('a')
list2.append(list1[:index] + list1[index+1:])
print list2
```

Comment: @ericksonla Check this.